# Get response from php script with curl after posting response

Tags: php, curl

I have a form which uses curl to submit the apiKey to my server and then the script on my server verify the key and returns true and false. but instead of response. I'm getting Trying to access array offset on value of type null. I want to know How to get response from my server after curl submission.

**Curl Submit**

```
    $post['apiKey'] = $apiKey;    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.pawnhost.com/phevapi/verify_api.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

     $json = curl_exec($ch);
     $response = json_decode($json, true);
```

**Server Script**

```
<?php 

define("ERROR_HEADER_URL", "Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?error=");

require("includes/initialize.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "invalidRequest");

$postParams = allowedPOSTParams($allowed_params=['apiKey']);

if (!isset($postParams['apiKey'])) header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "verficationFailed");

$apiKey = escape($postParams['apiKey']);

if (isInputEmpty($apiKey)) {
    header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "emptyFields");

} elseif (!$apiKey == 25) {
    header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . urlencode("invalidKey"));

} else {

    $response = [];

    if (getApiKeyUserDetails($apiKey, $connection)) {

        if (getApiKeyUserDetails($apiKey, $connection)['apiKeyUsed'] > 0) {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['error'] = 'apiKeyUsed';
        } else {
            makeApiKeyUsed($apiKey, $connection);
            $response['success'] = true;
        }

    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['error'] = 'invalidApiKey';
    }

    return json_encode($response);

}
```

**Allowed Post Params Function:**

```
function allowedPOSTParams($allowed_params=[]) {
    $allowed_array = [];
    foreach ($allowed_params as $param) {
        if (isset($_POST[$param])) {
            $allowed_array[$param] = $_POST[$param];
        } else {
            $allowed_array[$param] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return $allowed_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiKey);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('apiKey'=>$apiKey));
```

Then, you will able to find **apiKey** as **POST parameter**.

Comment: you're missing a parentheses. but it still shows Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: parentheses added, also can you share allowedPOSTParams definition. may error occurs from the same

Comment: Also, try to execute **print_r($_POST);** statement in server script, to check data is capturing or not.

Comment: Okay, I've added the allowedPostParams function in the question

Comment: have you checked post data with above statement?

Comment: it says empty fields

Comment: That's mean you have not set any value of $apiKey. print value of $apiKey before curl statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207940/discussion-between-lachiweb-and-flash).